# Android ArrayList populating unnecessary elements

Tags: android, arraylist

I am currently creating an app that fetches 2 Strings randomly from an arraylist.

This is what I did:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("someString");
// continue arrayList.add() for another thousand times for different strings.
// I am adding the Strings manually as these are specific questions in a quiz app

Random random = new Random();
myTextView.setText(arrayList.get(random.nextInt(arrayList.size());
myTextView2.setText(arrayList.get(random.nextInt(arrayList.size());
```

**The Question:**

At any point in time, I only need 2 Strings to be displayed to the user. But I am populating a thousand element arrayList, and fetching only 2 Strings from there. Is there a better way to do this? For example, only populating 2 Strings at runtime, without populating the unnecessary Strings?

Or maybe it does not matter at all?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you share some relevant code please?

Comment: Where are these `String`s coming from? Can you just randomly generate two, as needed?

Comment: Hi Varun, I have editted the question to include some code. Mike: Hi, these Strings are questions used in a quiz app to prompt the user, hence I am adding them manually instead of randomly generating

Comment: Hi Marcus, I think your code is fine. Maybe you can use an array to store these strings if they are static and you don't need to `add`  or `get`

Comment: Thanks Rust for your response! Hmm I guess I worried about the unnecessary mini stuff here haha